# Node.js "ws" websocket server randomly disconnects client after ~30 seconds, error 1006

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, networking, websocket

I have a simple websocket server like so:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server( { server: server, path: "/ws" });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, req) {

    console.log("Connected");
    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
    });

    ws.on('close', function close(code, reason) {
        console.log("Code: "+code+" | Reason: "+reason);
        console.log('disconnected');
    });

    ws.send('something');
});
```

I have a client that connects to it fine, but after about 30 seconds of connection, the websocket server closes the connection with an error code of "1006". Google tells me this means the connection was abnormally disrupted. However, I'm not sure what could be causing this. The `ws.on('error')` callback is also not triggered. How do I keep an indefinite/longer connection with my client?

Comment: I have a strong feeling this isn't random. Are you using a reverse proxy or something (such as nginx)?

Comment: Hi, yes I'm using nginx.What about nginx could be causing this? I previously followed this guide to enable the appropriate headers to allow websocket access: https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nginx has 30 seconds set as the default timeout.

You'll need to increase this number using a `proxy_read_timeout` directive.

For example, to extend the timeout to a day (which is probably overkill)

```
proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
```

Usually I set this in the `location` section, so that it can be overridden just for the websocket without impacting areas where it can be desirable to have the default.

Comment: This seems to be it! I have continuous connection now. Could you explain what the purpose of that directive is?

Comment: It's basically so that nginx doesn't get stuck trying to forward hung connections. Say you had a misbehaving webserver that just held the connection open because it froze for some reason. Nginx would eventually run out of resources to handle new requests. It's basically to protect against that. Remember that this was all decided before websockets or even long-polling was a desired feature.